# Issue with running Prettier: exit code 2 and unexpected token ':'

Tags: node.js, prettier, windows-11

Each time I try to commit or run `yarn format` (using this script : `"format": "prettier --config \"packages/**/*.{ts,tsx}\""`) or run `make fmt`, I got the following error knowing I don't have such error in my project :

```
PS C:\Users\GAMER\Desktop\hey-lady\web> make fmt
yarn format --write
yarn run v1.22.21
$ prettier --write "packages/**/*.{ts,tsx}" --write
[error] Invalid configuration for file "C:\Users\GAMER\Desktop\hey-lady\web\packages\app\components\AccountProfileEnglishLevel.tsx":
[error] Unexpected token ':'
error Command failed with exit code 2.
```

This is my env:

- Prettier v3.1.1
- Windows 11
- Node v18.19.0

This is my `.prettierrc` file config:

```json
{
  "semi": true,
  "tabWidth": 2,
  "printWidth": 120,
  "singleQuote": false,
  "trailingComma": "none",
  "arrowParens": "always" 
}
```

I tried to run Prettier to format my code and push it to GitHub repo but each time it ends with this error.

Answer (score 1):

Quick update, everyone! I resolved the issue by adjusting the link to the .prettierrc file in the package.json. The initial linting setup was configured for Linux, and the compatibility issue on Windows prompted this change

Answer (score -1):

try running the following command:

```
prettier --config .prettierrc --write "packages/app/components/AccountProfileEnglishLevel.tsx"
```

if that doesn't helps, try this:

```
yarn global upgrade prettier
```

Comment: None of these worked :( may windows or eslint be the prob ?